# Read multilingual data

Tags: r, encoding, import, multilingual

I am trying to read data in which there are more than one language text data.

While reading in R , I am using below syntax.

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "Japanese")
df <- read.csv(file = "Japanese.csv",  encoding = "UTF-8",header=T,na.strings=c(""))
```

if file contains Japanese text, I am able to read Japanese character correctly, but script not able to read Chinese character. 
I am getting below when I try to view data in R in place of Chinese text.

```
<U+95EE><U+9898>
```

Can anyone help if we can read data having more than 2 language text data.

Below is example data I am using

```
Num Group   Text
1   Group1  パスワードの問題
2   Group1  ログインに関する問題
3   Group2  システムに関する問題
4   Group2  问题与内存
5   Group3  问题与登录
6   Group3  与系统问题
```

Comment: Can that be done robustly in any language? (I don't know, just asking.)

Comment: How are you "viewing" the data? It doesn't matter how many "languages" are in a file, it just matters how the file was encoded (and a file can only have one encoding). So are you sure it's a UTF-8 file? The locale shouldn't matter in that case. Just try to `cat()` the column to see the un-escaped data.

Comment: @MrFlick, Yes it's UTF-8 file. I am viewing data in R environment. using view(df) command. If set local is default script is not reading correctly text data in different language available in column

Comment: Without a reproducible example, we're forced to just guess what's going on. What's the `Encoding()` on that column after import. Are you using the `View()` in Rstudio or the default R GUI? What OS are you using? Is another file viewer able to read and show the different language chunks? It still doesn't seem likely that the same file would contain two different Encodings.

Comment: @MrFlick, I will edit original question with example data. Encoding is UTF-8 on column post import. Yes, I am using view() in Rstudio. I am using windows10 OS.

Comment: The file encoding is just fine. The problem is specific to Windows+R+Rstudio. Windows doesn't seem to support "true" UTF-8 encoding and converts everything to the system locale. Are you running R 3.5 yet? Supposedly this was supposed to get better in the latest release.

Comment: @MrFlick, I a using R3.5, seems there is newer version 3.5.1 is availble will try newer version and check if we can load multilingual data.

Comment: @MrFlick, Tried to load multilingual data with latest version 3.5.1 but it is not working

Comment: Check out this article: http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/. Windows simply will not display all the characters when you just use `print.data.frame` or `View`. However if you do `df$Text` you should see the correct characters. The data is there correctly, it just doesn't display the way you might expect.

Comment: @MrFlick, Thanks a lot. This is very useful article. I am able to view correct text when printed in R console. Let me try to process NLP of these text. Hopefully it will work. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below - Sorry don't have any Japanese text handy to test it.

```
   df<- read.csv("your_file.csv", fileEncoding="cp932")
```

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 platform